# Is it possible to import questions to Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support

Not sure if it right place to ask this question.

We have a selenium-user forum at Google groups and we are trying hard to get Selenium dedicated site at area 51. Site is in the commit stage now and is available here - 
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium

Our users at Google groups have been asking if it were possible to import questions from Google Groups to Stack Exchange site. I am not sure if it is possible, is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Provide a migration path for users of VBulletin to an SE site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84267/provide-a-migration-path-for-users-of-vbulletin-to-an-se-site) and [Plugin to submit forum posts to StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79600/plugin-to-submit-forum-posts-to-stackoverflow/79604#79604)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The reason is because SE really isn't a forum—the back and forth between OP and responders don't work well with the asker and answerer system, especially since posts like "You need to give us more info" become comments, "Here's the solution" become answers, and "Thanks" get deleted. Because of all the different things that would need to be attended to in a migration, no migration feature was designed for SE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion,

why not migrate all selenium google group messages as "Here' the solution", meaning none of them is considered a comment on a post. then tag all of these messages as #MigratedFromGoogle or something like that.

Comment: Looks good idea and would really keep our existing Selenium users happy. I am not sure if you suggest to do so or also confirm that it is possible to do so on SE site. Do you?

Comment: sorry Tarun, but i didn't understand your question. I can't confirm 'if its possible on SE' since im a very fresh SE user ;). would i take part in migrating the data from google to SE? is that what you are asking? im more than happy to help

Comment: Hey Lutfi, You answered my question any way:-) I suppose I know you on Google Selenium Groups and would add you in my contact soon. I am glad to see your enthusiasm in participating possible data migration and even if not that I am sure you would be great helper to Selenium Users on area51 site